# Why static files are served on Heroku without activating WhiteNoise?

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-staticfiles

I followed a tutorial on deploying Django app on Heroku server and I stumble across this:

- I have installed WhiteNoise package for serving statics
- Added inside **settings.py**:

> ```
> MIDDLEWARE = [
>     'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
> ]
> ```

But **omitted** to activate it inside **wsgi.py** file:

```
from whitenoise import WhiteNoise
from my_project import MyWSGIApp
    application = MyWSGIApp()
    application = WhiteNoise(application, root='/path/to/static/files')
    application.add_files('/path/to/more/static/files', prefix='more-files/')
```

Why the static files are served on the production site ? Should not the above code be responsible for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wsgi.py` integration hasn't been [required](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/changelog.html#simpler-cleaner-django-middleware-integration) since v3.0 and was [removed](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/changelog.html#v4-0) in v4.0.

Comment: Great, thanks. Makes sense now that I had a closer look in their documentation for v4 they have the integration in wsgi steps written in `QuickStart for other WSGI apps` section. This is not addressed to Django then.